# Think of a number beginning with

Tags: english

A while ago, I was watching a video about teaching children to count when these challenges suddenly occurred to me. Note that they may be easy in other languages (eg. in German you have: eins, zwei, drei which will solve the last one) so I’m limiting the answers to English only.

> 1. Think of a number beginning with “t”.
> 2. Think of a number beginning with “o”.
> 3. Think of a number beginning with “p”.
> 4. Think of a number beginning with “m”.
> 5. Think of a number beginning with “z”.

**Edit:** Also, all numbers are less than a billion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle.

Comment: The point about this was that it was meant to be a deflection for those who like to think naturally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

> the number pi ($\pi$). It has a constant value but still it's a number.

Comment: Yes - that was the one I was looking for (pi). The point of the puzzle was that it was meant to trick the reader into thinking natural numbers.

Comment: You probably mean pi, not pie.

Comment: Corrected the spelling. Blame the Auto complete

Comment: I selected this answer, as this was the main heart of the challenges, whilst the others were just deflections.

Answer (score 6):

Two; one; pentillion; million; zero.

Comment: Not pentillion.

Comment: @QuestionAsker: I answered your question. What else do you want?

Comment: @QuestionAsker: I'm confused. It's a number beginning with p - what's wrong with it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it - except it wasn't the number I was looking for. I didn't see that loophole so I edited the question.

Comment: @Deusovi is pentillion even in use anywhere? "Quintillion" is the one I'm familiar with, and I'm only seeing pentillion in a list of *proposed* number-words (and anyone can propose something)

Comment: @question_asker: Yeah, it's *far* less common than "quintillion", but still occasionally in use. (For example, in a Duke University article on the first Google results page for "pentillion".)

Comment: @Deusovi Ah, that one didn't show up until the second page for me